# Is there a way to grab data from multiple Pdfs

Tags: excel, file, pdf, powerquery

I have a large set of pdf file, each file has a certain number of rows, lets say product references and price. These keep changing as files change.
For example the input pdf file could be :

File 1

Invoice number : 1

1. Product a : 5000
2. Product b : 3000
3. Product d : 6000

File 2 :

Invoice number : 2

1. Product b : 5000
2. Product c : 1000

I need these outputted in an excel sheet with product references and invoice no as headers and the values in rows.

I tried with power query but since the values of each row aren’t constant it didn’t work.

Is there a way that I can do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You stated "I tried with power query but since the values of each row aren’t constant it didn’t work." Why is this the problem, can you clarify?

Comment: I may have over simplified the problem, In fact I have thousands of Salary Slips, each one contains personnal informations that i need to grab then the different types of earnings/bonuses/allowance etc. I need to prepare a payroll analysis, and in order to do so I need the data in a horizontal way : name / social security/ hourly rate/allowance a/ allowance b ...etc . I hope I made it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the invoice number to the product reference.

[image]

[image]

Considering that you imported the data. Below is the power query after the imported steps of your example.

```
  ...
  #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "test", each Text.Contains([Column1],"Invoice number")),
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Invoice Number", each if [test] then Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1],": ") else null),
  #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Invoice Number"}),
  #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Product reference", each if [test]= false then Text.BeforeDelimiter(Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1],". ")," : ") & "_" &[Invoice Number] else null),
  #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Values", each if [test]=false then Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1],": ") else null),
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom3", each ([Product reference] <> null)),
  #"Removed Other Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Invoice Number", "Product reference", "Values"})
in
  #"Removed Other Columns2"
```

If the answer works for you, the expectation is that you checkmark it and upvote it. If the answer does not work for you you add a comment at the bottom and the problem you experience. For your situation **you will need to adapt the answer**.

Comment: This gave me a really good Idea thank you